# Managing PYTHONPATH for development environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonpath

I'm developing several different Python packages with my team.  Say that we have `~/src/pkg1`, `~/src/pkg2`, and `~/src/pkg3`.  How do we add these to `PYTHONPATH` without each of us having to manage dot-files?

We could add, say, `~/src/site/sitecustomize.py`, which is added once to `PYTHONPATH`, but is it "guaranteed" that there won't be a global `sitecustomize.py`.

virtualenv seems like the wrong solution, because we don't want to have to build/install the packages after each change.

Comment: I think you have tagged your question as virtualenv, have tried using it?

Comment: With `virtualenv` you don't build / install packages after each change, you just activate the environment (`. bin/activate`) prior to running the code (that's assuming you're using symlinked development eggs for your own packages).

Comment: If someone adds a new package, I'd like to avoid having to "virtualenv -e" in ~/src/pkg1, ~/src/pkg2, ~/src/pkg3, etc. for every member of the team.

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of options...

### 1) Why not dotfiles?

You could centralize the management of dotfiles with a centralized repository and optionally with version control. I use a Dropbox folder named `dotfiles` but many people use `github` or other services like that to manage dotfiles.

If you do that, you will guarantee every people on your development team to share some dotfiles. So you could define a dotfile say `.python_proys` which export the appropriate `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` which by convention every developer should `source` in their environment.

Suppose **pkg1** is only an script, **pkg2** is an script and also a module and **pk3** is only a module. Then, python_proys Example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/src/pkg1:~/src/pkg2
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/src/pkg2:~/src/pkg3
```

And then, every developer have to `source` this dotfile somewhere by convetion. Each one will do the way he like. One could `source` the dotfile manually before using the packages. Another one could `source` it in his `.bashrc` or `.zshenv` or whatever dotfile apply to him.

The idea is to have one centralized point of coordination and only one dotfile to maintain: the .python_proys dotfile.

### 2) Use symlinks

You could define a directory in your home, like `~/dist` (for modules) and `~/bin` (for scripts) and set symbolic links there to the specific pakages in `~/src/`, and make every developer have this `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` setting:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/dist
```

So, using the same example at *Why not dotfiles?*, where **pkg1** is only an script, **pkg2** is an script and also a module and **pkg3** is only a module, then you could symlink like:

```
cd ~/bin
ln -s ../src/pkg1
ln -s ../src/pkg2
cd ~/dist
ln -s ../src/pkg2
ln -s ../src/pkg3
```

Those commands could be do automatically with an script. You could write a bootstrap script, or simply copy and paste the commands and save it in a shell script. In any way, maintain it and centralize it the same way i explain it before.

This way the .dotfiles will not change, only the script defining the symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't add a python module to `PYTHONPATH`, you just add the path component.

If you want all your team to be working on some python package, you can install the package as editable with the [`-e` option](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#options) in a virtual environment.

This way you can continue development and you don't have to mess with the `PYTHONPATH`.  Keep in mind that the working directory is always included in the `PYTHONPATH`, so unless you have an external requirement; you don't need a virtual environment, just the source in your working directory.

Your workflow would be the following:

1. Create virtual environment
2. Create a [`.pth` file](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path), to modify your `PYTHONPATH`.
3. Work as usual.

This would be my preferred option.  If you have a standard layout across your projects, you can distribute a customized [bootstrap script](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#creating-your-own-bootstrap-scripts) which will create the environment, and then adjust the `PYTHONPATH` automatically.  Share this bootstrap script across the team, or add it as part of the source repository.

Comment: Each package has modules ~/src/pkg1/mod1/_init_.py, ~/src/pkg2/mod2/__init__.py, etc. The directories ~/src/pkg1, etc. therefore need to be in the path to see mod1, mod2, etc.  With virtualenv -e, every coworker would have to run it for every project.  I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into creating a *name*.pth path configuration file as outlined in the[`site`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site)module's documentation. These files can hold multiple paths that will be added to`sys.path`and be easily edited since they're simply text files.

Comment: These are development packages in people's home directories, not in the site directory.

Comment: The paths put in a .pth file can reference directories anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that your other modules are at predictable path (relative to $0)

We can compute absolute path of $0

```
os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])
```

then arrive at your module path and append it

```
sys.path.append(something)
```